# Telerik text selection

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik, radgrid, itemcommand

I have a telerik radgrid, like shown underneath

```
| Username | Password   |
-------------------------
| A_user   | *****      |
| A_user2  | *****      |
| A_user3  | *****      |
```

When I click one of the rows, it will display the password of the clicked row, like so:

```
| Username | Password   |
-------------------------
| A_user   | *****      |
| A_user2  | A password |
| A_user3  | *****      |
```

That works fine. I am proceeding this way because the decryption of the password is a rather complicated and long process, so decrypting one password at a time is less time consuming, especially when the user doesn't need all the passwords.

When I have the password displayed, I'd like to be able to select the password in the grid to copy it. Unfortunately, the radgrid will fire the "RowClick" itemcommand once more, and the row gets de-selected. Therefore, I cannot copy the passwords.

My question is: **Is there a way to cancel the itemcommand of a radgrid under certain circumstances?**
I'd like to be able to disable the itemcommand event when the password is already decrypted.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
I guess I should also be mentioning that I'm using a radajaxloadingpanel to display an animation over the grid when it's loading. Even when the itemcommand method does nothing, the ajaxloadingpanel is displayed and the text I try to highlight is de-selected.

**More edits:**

Here is my radgrid code

```
<telerik:RadGrid id="radGridAccounts" runat="server" Width="99%" PageSize="20" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" 
                        AllowFilteringByColumn="True" ShowStatusBar="true" EnableLinqExpressions="False" GridLines="None"
                        AllowMultiRowSelection="false">

                        <ClientSettings EnableRowHoverStyle="true" EnablePostBackOnRowClick="true" AllowKeyboardNavigation="false">
                            <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" />
                            <KeyboardNavigationSettings EnableKeyboardShortcuts="false" />
                        </ClientSettings>
        <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric" PagerTextFormat=""/>

        <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" EditMode="InPlace" CommandItemDisplay="Top"
                            InsertItemDisplay="Top" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" NoMasterRecordsText="Aucun compte"
                            InsertItemPageIndexAction="ShowItemOnCurrentPage" DataKeyNames="USERN" >


        <Columns>
        <%--Username--%>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="USERN" DataField="USERN" HeaderText="Username" 
                                    AllowFiltering="true" ColumnEditorID="radUsernameEditor"/>
        <%--Password--%>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="PASWR" DataField="PASWR" HeaderText="Password"
                                    AllowFiltering="false" ColumnEditorID="radPasswordEditor" />
        <%--Edit--%>
        <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn ButtonType="ImageButton"
                                    InsertImageUrl=".\Images\ok.gif" UpdateImageUrl=".\Images\ok.gif" CancelImageUrl=".\Images\cancel.gif" />
        <%--Delete--%>
        <telerik:GridButtonColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" 
                                ImageUrl=".\Images\delete.gif" />
        </Columns>
    <CommandItemSettings AddNewRecordText="" RefreshText="" />

    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

And my ItemCommand code:

```
Protected Sub radGridAccounts_ItemCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs) Handles radGridAccounts.ItemCommand

Try

    If (e.CommandName = "RowClick" AndAlso TypeOf e.Item Is GridDataItem) Then
        e.Item.Selected = True

        For Each item As GridDataItem In radGridAccounts.Items

            If Not item.IsInEditMode Then
                If item.Selected Then
                    'Decrypt the password method
                Else 
                    item.Cells(4).Text = "*****"
                End If

            End If

        Next

    End If

Catch ex As Exception
    DisplayMessage("Error : " & ex.Message, MessageType.Err)
End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: can you post up your radgrid code only, just interested in which commands you're using

Comment: Thank you for looking into my problem. I've added the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to OnSelectedIndexChanged function on the radGrid and store the current selected row in a clientside variable, and handle the rowSelected client event and either cancel or allow the postback to happen, also add in the ClientDataKeyName that you want to use.

```
<telerik:RadGrid id="radGridAccounts" runat="server" Width="99%" PageSize="20" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadGridAccounts_SelectedIndexChanged"
                        AllowFilteringByColumn="True" ShowStatusBar="true" EnableLinqExpressions="False" GridLines="None"
                        AllowMultiRowSelection="false">

                        <ClientSettings EnableRowHoverStyle="true" EnablePostBackOnRowClick="true" EnableAllowKeyboardNavigation="false">
                            <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" />
                            <KeyboardNavigationSettings EnableKeyboardShortcuts="false" />
     <ClientEvents OnRowSelected="rowSelected" />
    </ClientSettings>
        <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric" PagerTextFormat=""/>

        <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" EditMode="InPlace" CommandItemDisplay="Top"
                            InsertItemDisplay="Top" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" NoMasterRecordsText="Aucun compte"
                            InsertItemPageIndexAction="ShowItemOnCurrentPage" DataKeyNames="USERN" ClientDataKeyNames="USERN" >


        <Columns>
         ...
        </Columns>
    <CommandItemSettings AddNewRecordText="" RefreshText="" />

    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>



 <script type="text/javascript">
 var selectedUserName;//global js var 
  function rowSelected(senders, args) 
  {
        //get the ClientDataKeyName
        var rowUserName= args.getDataKeyValue("USERN");
        if(selectedUserName == rowUserName){
              args.set_cancel(true);//cancel the postback
        }   
  }
 </script>
```

Then on the server-side:

```
  protected void RadGridAccounts_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RadGridAccounts.SelectedItems == null || RadGridAccounts.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
            return;

        var dataItem = RadGridAccounts.SelectedItems[0] as GridDataItem;
        if (dataItem != null)
        {
           //do the password look up 
        }
    }
```

Comment: you'll have to work out the c# to vb.net that I posted, just saw that you posted your code behind, your code slightly tweaked should work in selectedIndexChanged

Comment: I'm used to converting c# to vb, no worries. I'll try this out and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: added some more code for you to try.. enablePostBackOnRowClick and add a client event RowSelected.  You can cancel the postback on RowSelected if you're reSelecting the same row using args.set_cancel(true);

Comment: Not sure on the -1 it solved the op problem, and is clearly not the complete code for a page that will compile, nor is it meant to be.